# Return multiple lines into list

Tags: python

I have Result:

```
Alice
Washington Street
Doctor
Wong Li
Lincoln Street
Teacher
Suresh
Hamilton Street
Engineer
```

I can turn it into list by:

```
>>>result_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in result.splitlines()) if y] #which i found it in SO
>>>result_list
['Alice', 'Washington Street', 'Doctor', 'Wong Li', 'Lincoln Street', 'Teacher', 'Suresh', 'Hamilton Street', 'Engineer']
```

But what I need is

```
[['Alice', 'Washington Street', 'Doctor'], ['Wong Li', 'Lincoln Street', 'Teacher'], ['Suresh', 'Hamilton Street', 'Engineer']]
```

...basically group it by every 3 lines

After that I will use pandas to tabulate it into three column of name, address and occupation.

Comment: Do you understand what is happening in your code? I do not see any effort made by you, just some 'copy and paste' operations. I would give you an answer like rep "lovers" do but you will not understand it.

Comment: @ElisByberi [This](https://i.imgur.com/SZPjHwz.jpg) is a very popular coding text. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I have browsed it!

Comment: Where is `result` coming from? If you read the entire contents of a file into a single string, tt would probably be easier to process if you read one line at a time from the original source.

Answer (score 2):

Build a list of the desired slices using appropriate values by a range with proper `start, stop, step` values:

```
result_list = [result_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(result_list), 3)]
# [['Alice', 'Washington Street', 'Doctor'], ['Wong Li', 'Lincoln Street', 'Teacher'], ['Suresh', 'Hamilton Street', 'Engineer']]
```

Comment: Here's another option, although if you're unfamiliar with this idiom it is harder to read: `[*zip(*[iter(result_list)]*3)]`

Comment: Yea, I just realised, I answered a similar question earlier that *did* require the offset...

Comment: @PM2Ring I like that approach. But it is cryptic :)

Comment: @ElisByberi True, but in Python 2, you can simply do `zip(*[iter(result_list)]*3)`, and in early Python 3's just wrap that in `list()`

Comment: The downside of that chunking technique is that it loses final partial chunks (although that may be desirable in some situations). OTOH, you can use `zip_longest` (or `izip_longest` in Py 2) and supply a fillvalue.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the list `result_list` like you did and then use list comprehension with appropriate slicing..

```
result_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in result.splitlines()) if y]

result_list = [result_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(result_list), 3)]

# output : [['Alice', 'Washington Street', 'Doctor'], ['Wong Li', 'Lincoln Street', 'Teacher'], ['Suresh', 'Hamilton Street', 'Engineer']]
```